# Why I get this result in my own code for the nth root?

Tags: c, function, pow

I'm trying to do my own code to calculate the nth root of a number. It works fine for numbers in the order of magnitude of 10<sup>9</sup>, but for bigger numbers it gives me weird things.

```
double nroot(double a, double b) {
    int j;
    double i, wtemp, w, xf, x, bgint, lsint, eps = 0.000000001, delta;

    if (b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (a == 1)
        return b;
    while (xf < (int)b) {
        i++;
        xf = power(i, a);
    }
    if (xf == b)
        return i;
    if (xf == b && a < 0)
        return 1 / i;   
    else {
        bgint = i;
        lsint = i - 1;      
        for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) { 
            x = ((b - power(lsint, ABS(a))) / (xf - power(lsint, ABS(a)))) * (bgint - lsint);   
            w = lsint + x;
            delta = w - wtemp;
            if (ABS(delta) < eps) {
                return w;
            } else {    
                lsint += x;
                wtemp = w;              
            }
        }
        if (a > 0)
            return w;
        else
            return 1 / w;
    }
}
```

Where `power()` is a function I wrote:

```
double power(double a, double b) {
    int countPower;
    double result;
    if (b >= 0) {
        for (result = 1, countPower = 0; countPower < (int)b; countPower++)                 
            result *= a;
    } else {
        for (result = 1, countPower = (int)-b; countPower > 0; countPower--)                    
            result /= a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The thing is this: If a do `nroot(2, 10000000000) /* 10.000.000.000 */` I get `-1.000002`.

I don't understand where does this result come from because if I do `nroot(2, 1000000000) /* 1.000.000.000 */` I get `31622.776599`, which is the correct result.

Any review will be appreciated.

Comment: Your first job is to see if using the standard `pow` function addresses the issue. By the way, (n)th root stuff can be solved with Newton Raphson. Your algorithm looks unstable and potentially defective to me.

Comment: How is defined `ABS()`?

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every* function that you use, and http://floating-point-gui.de/ ; for your next question, provide some [MCVE]

Comment: If you are not planning to support fractional roots, the corresponding arguments should be `int`s and not `double`s.

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually I know my function power doesn't work for very large number but now I think I know why. Also, I know there are other methods that can work better, I just doing in this way to prove the efficiency.  By the way, the problem was in the `while` .

Comment: @purplepsycho I defined that as a macro `#define ABS(X) ((X)<0)?-1*(X):(X)`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @n.m. It is defined as a double because it is part of a kind of calculator y I using only two inputs which are doubles.That what I defined them in that way.

Comment: Then you should convert the second argument to `int` *before* calling nroot`, and also check and give an error message if it has any fractional part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because `xf` is uninitialized in `while (xf < (int)b) {`.

It works only by chance in some cases... Furthermore, casting `b` as `(int)` is unnecessary and counterproductive if `b` is larger than `INT_MAX`, around 2 billion on 32-bit systems. Note that `i` is uninitialized as well. You should probably set both `i` and `xf` to `1` before this loop:

```
i = xf = 1;    
while (xf < b) {
    i++;
    xf = power(i, a);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I did'n notice that, now the code works enough well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `power` function seem ok.

Your problem comes from this line:

```
while(xf<(int)b)
```

You cast `b` to an integer, certainly 32 bits by default, which maximum value is about `2e9` (see `INT_MAX`).

So when `b` is over `INT_MAX`, your code do no longer work.

To correct the problem, just remove the cast, the code becomes:

```
while (xf < b)
{ 
    i++;
    xf = power(i, a);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think that and the fact that my variables i and xf was not initialized, was the problem.